# How provide a different bean implementation to @Autowire field based on annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-config

I have a config class that provides two implemenations of the same base bean interface. I want these to be set on the autowired fields conditionally based on an annotation on the field.

```
public class MyController
{
    @Autowired
    private MyBeanInterface base;

    @Autowired
    @MyAnnotation
    private MyBeanInterface special;
}
```

This is a pesudo-code of the config class:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClass
{
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MyBeanInterface getNormalBeanInterface()
    {
        return new MyBeanInterfaceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    //This doesn't work
    @ConditionalOnClass(MyAnnotation.class)
    public MyBeanInterface getSpecialBeanInterface()
    {
        return new MyBeanInterfaceForMyAnnotation();
    }
}
```

How can I make the annotated field be populated by the second bean?

Comment: Cant we use @Qualifier annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Qualifier](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_qualifier_annotation.htm) annotation. Example:

**Controller:**

Add Qualifier annotation at the injected fields with bean id as parameter:

```
public class MyController
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("normalBean")
    private MyBeanInterface base;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("specialBean")
    private MyBeanInterface special;
}
```

**ConfigClass**

Specify bean id:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClass
{
    @Bean(name="normalBean")
    @Primary
    public MyBeanInterface getNormalBeanInterface()
    {
        return new MyBeanInterfaceImpl();
    }

    @Bean(name="specialBean")
    public MyBeanInterface getSpecialBeanInterface()
    {
        return new MyBeanInterfaceForMyAnnotation();
    }
}
```